# What does an antivirus software actually monitor?

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, antivirus

I experience some slowness in a MFC/WPF interop user interface as long as the antivirus software (V3Pro Virus checker, Sophos antivirus) is enabled. As soon as it is disabled everything is fast again.

I am suprised that the antivirus causes this, because my application does not do any file access. I double checked that with [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). The process does not query any files. So I wonder if there is anything else apart from files that antivirus can monitor. What else should I watch out for to track down this odd behavior?

UPDATE: To make the GUI slowness occur I need to switch between two MFC dialogs that contain WPF screens.

Comment: What your application actually do when this slowness occurs?

Comment: I need to switch between two screens to make it slow.

Comment: Virus scanners can scan the registry, your memory, your currently executing code (sometimes), e-mail monitoring, Internet traffic, etc. Is your application intensive in any of those areas? Also, why *two* scanners at once? That's enough to slow ANY system down.

Comment: @Cory: It is V3Pro Virus checker on some machines and it is Sophos antivirus on other machines. 
Yes, our application is intensive on executing code. How or in what way is antivirus software "checking executing code"?

Comment: I don't think they literally interpret executing code (unless it's JavaScript or something easily interceptable), but I imagine some could be able to detect memory hijacking or other methods viruses use to inject themselves all over your computer. Perhaps they can read information from Windows' DEP (data execution prevention). Do you know if it's your CPU or GPU that's getting pegged?

Answer (score 0):

You could selectively turn off features in Sophos Anti-Virus to work out what is delaying things. I'd suggest BOPS would be the most likely candidate. It also might be suspicious activity montitoring?